# How do I make copies of an array in python based on conditions in the array?

Tags: python, numpy, combinatorics

I have an

```
n = np.array([[1, 12, 1, 3],
              [1, 1, 12, 0]])
```

and would like to duplicate it such that if I have a double-digit number in the array, it breaks the array into two identical arrays where the first array has the first digit and the second array has the second digit. In the above example, I would have 4 copies of the matrix. The assumptions are that there are either single digit or double digit numbers in the array.

```
n1 = [1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 0]
n2 = [1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 2, 0]
n3 = [1, 2, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 0]
n4 = [1, 2, 1, 3], [1, 1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: Is the assumption that there won't be any numbers more than 2 digits?

Comment: ... or more than one number with 2 digits

Comment: Can the size of the array of arrays be any size? Are the numbers only ever 2 digits? Sounds like a permutation problem, could you specify more constraints?

Comment: Uh, what should happen if there is say, the 12 in the second row were a 2?

Comment: Yes, the assumption is there can be any 2 digit number. The size of the array can be any size. The numbers are only ever 2 digits. If it was 2 in the second row instead of 12, then there would only be 2 matrices.

Comment: All other things being equal, if `n[1,1]` was also `12`, how many matrices should be in the output?

Comment: If you mean n [12,12] then there should be 4 outputs. n[12,1] should give you 2 outputs and n[1,1] should just output the same matrix.

Comment: No, I meant if the input was `np.array([[1, 12, 1, 3], [1, 12, 12, 0]])`

Comment: Oh sorry. If it was that then there would be 8 matrices in the output. 2 * 2 * 2 = 8

Comment: Is not that clear? So in fact you want to connect the two lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach 1: `itertools.product`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from itertools import product
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> 
>>> n = np.array([[1, 12, 1, 3],
...               [1, 1, 12, 0]])
>>> 
>>> pprint([np.reshape(nn, n.shape).astype(int) for nn in product(*map(str, n.ravel()))])
[array([[1, 1, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]]),
 array([[1, 1, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 2, 0]]),
 array([[1, 2, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]]),
 array([[1, 2, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 2, 0]])]
```

Note that this happens to work also for longer numbers.

```
>>> n = np.array([462, 3, 15, 1, 0])
>>> pprint([np.reshape(nn, n.shape).astype(int) for nn in product(*map(str, n.ravel()))])
[array([4, 3, 1, 1, 0]),
 array([4, 3, 5, 1, 0]),
 array([6, 3, 1, 1, 0]),
 array([6, 3, 5, 1, 0]),
 array([2, 3, 1, 1, 0]),
 array([2, 3, 5, 1, 0])]
```

### Approach 2: `np.meshgrid`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> n = np.array([[1, 12, 1, 3],
...               [1, 1, 12, 0]])
>>> 
>>> te = np.where(n>=10)
>>> dims = tuple(np.log10(n[te]).astype(int) + 1)
>>> 
>>> out = np.empty(dims + n.shape, dtype=n.dtype)
>>> out[...] = n
>>> out[(Ellipsis,) + te] = np.moveaxis(np.meshgrid(*(s//10**np.arange(i)[::-1]%10 for i, s in zip(dims, n[te])), indexing='ij'), 0, -1)
>>> 
>>> out
array([[[[1, 1, 1, 3],
         [1, 1, 1, 0]],

        [[1, 1, 1, 3],
         [1, 1, 2, 0]]],


       [[[1, 2, 1, 3],
         [1, 1, 1, 0]],

        [[1, 2, 1, 3],
         [1, 1, 2, 0]]]])
```